# Concatenation of variable value and string in apache hive

Tags: string, apache-hive

In apache Hive CLI or Beeline CLI, I need to concatenate value of a variable with a string. Is it possible to do so?

Example:
set path_on_hdfs="/apps/hive/warehouse/my_db.db";

how to get something like '${hivevar:path_on_hdfs}/myTableName'?

Comment: @Taegost tried built-in concat function and bash style concatenation, but non of them worked.

Comment: Please include that information in your question, along with specifics as to what exactly you tried, and how those attempts failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

set path_on_hdfs= /test1/test2

create external table test(id int)
location '${hiveconf:path_on_hdfs}/myTable';

is should work...